# How do I send Twitch.tv chat messages in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A recent update allows Minecraft to natively stream to twitch.tv and the chat also shows up in game... however I can't figure out how-to respond in a way that the twitch.tv users can see.

How do I send Twitch.tv chat messages using the in-game Minecraft chat menu?

Comment: Twitch users should be able to see your game chat, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently to do this; only though the twitch site.
Here is a video to help (also prove) you:

Comment: Could you please summarize the video in case it ever gets taken down? Then it still helps future users.

Comment: Unfortunately you're correct. This should be a feature, especially given Minecraft's natively-low, streaming resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you type into the in-game chat, the viewers watching your stream can see the words through the stream video.

Comment: Sure.... but the natively stream built into Minecraft is typically too low quality to read, and don't forget about users that are in chat only.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, fire up Minecraft today and update to the latest version. Once you’ve finished updating, proceed to the in-game options and select “Broadcast Settings” to begin inputing your Twitch credentials. Twitch for Minecraft is currently available for Windows (Vista and later) and Mac (10.7 and later). Once you’re all set up, the default hotkeys are as follows:

F6: Start/Stop Stream |

F7: Pause/Unpause Stream |

F8: Show Commercials (Partners)

*Directly from the Mojang website.*